# Bcrypt with django login

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with setting up my login system.

First off, when a user registers, I store their hashed password in the database which is generated in the front end like this:

```
var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
```

Now when the user logs in, I need to compare a plaintext password against the hashed password in order to get a result. Afterwards I want to return a message with the token and user.accountType in the response. How do I go about doing this?

This is my code so far:

```
class UserLogin(views.APIView):
    """
    User Login
    HTTP POST
    """
    def post(self, request):
        if not request.data:
            response_details = {
                    'message': "Please provide a valid email and password.",
                    'code': "400",
                    'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            response_details = {
                    'message': "Invalid email address.",
                    'code': "400",
                    'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])

        if user:
            print(user)
            # if bcrypt.hashpw(request.data['password'], user['password']):
            #     print("It matches")
            # else:
            #     print("It does not match")

            payload = {
                'email': user.email,
                'account_type': user.account_type
            }
            jwt_token = {'token': jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET_KEY")}

            response_details = {
                'data': json.dumps(jwt_token),
                'message': 'Login success!',
                'code': "200",
                'status': HTTP_200_OK
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
        else:
            response_details = {
                'message': "Invalid username and password combination.",
                'code': "400",
                'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
```

Comment: Why don't you use the build-in bcrypt in Django like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django)?

Comment: Didn't realise the feature existed until today. I guess I was trying to mimic what I had on the front end

Comment: Another point, you shouldn't take data from the request. This is unsecure. Use better from the form cleaned_data.